# parse a string with name-value pairs

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, parsing, linq-to-sql

How can I parse the following string of name-value pair in C#:

```
string studentDetail = "StudentId=J1123,FirstName=Jack,LastName=Welch,StudentId=k3342,FirstName=Steve,LastName=Smith"
```

The purpose of parsing this array is to insert values in DB using Linq to SQL:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveStudent(string studentDetail)
{
    DataContext db = new DataContext();         

    Student student = new Student();
    {
        student.StudentID = //StudentID
        student.FirstName = //FirstName
        student.LastName = //LastName
    };

    db.Student.InsertOnSubmit(student);
    db.SubmitChanges();

    return View();
}
```

What is the best way of approaching this?

Comment: still looks like just a string, not a string[]

Comment: still not a string[]. Perhaps you mean something like: var array = new string[] { "StudentId=J1123,FirstName=Jack,LastName=Welch", "StudentId=k3342,FirstName=Steve,LastName=Smith" };

Comment: @Jonathan I receive it in the following format:
"StudentId=J1123,FirstName=Jack,LastName=Welch,StudentId=k3342,FirstName=Steve,LastName=Smith"

Comment: @user793468 And they're all telling you that it's not a string array, it's just a [single] string.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can split on the comma, then on the equals sign.  I put the data into a dictionary for easy access.

```
string input = "StudentId=J1123,FirstName=Jack,LastName=Welch";

Dictionary<string,string> keyValuePairs = input.Split(',')
  .Select(value => value.Split('='))
  .ToDictionary(pair => pair[0], pair => pair[1]);

string studentId = keyValuePairs["StudentId"];
```

Note that this isn't validating the input at all to ensure that there are no commas in values, no keys without values, missing keys, etc.

Comment: All this time and I never knew ToDictionary had an overload which took the keys and values.

Comment: Great answer, would you point me to the solution for KeyValuePair<string, string> instead of string? (Or a Tuple<string, string>)?? I have duplicate values and I need to parse my string with those duplicates available.

Comment: duplicate key exception due to the key appearing multiple times in the string.

Comment: This answer does not work with the original data from the question. `System.ArgumentException: 'An item with the same key has already been added. Key: StudentId'`

Answer (score 5):

Because the individual student records are not delimited in the input, I would do something like the following:

```
public class Student
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

and then:

```
private List<Student> DoSplit(string input)
{
    var theReturn = new List<Student>();
    input = input.Replace(",StudentId=", "|,StudentId=");

    var students = input.Split('|');

    foreach (var student in students)
    {
        var attribs = student.Split(',');
        if (attribs.Count() == 3)
        {
            var s = new Student();
            s.Id = attribs[0].Substring(attribs[0].LastIndexOf('='));
            s.FirstName = attribs[1].Substring(attribs[1].LastIndexOf('='));
            s.LastName = attribs[2].Substring(attribs[2].LastIndexOf('='));

            theReturn.Add(s);
        }
    }

    return theReturn;
}
```

Again, it's a  bit naive because if content contains "=", ",", or "|", there will be failures. You should add some checking in there as well.

Comment: This is the correct answer and actually answers the OPs question.

Answer (score 4):

Eric Petroelje had a very nice answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/2049079/59996

> Try [System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150046.aspx), passing in everything
>   after the question mark. You would need to use the System.Web
>   assembly, but it shouldn't require a web context.

(I'm not sure why these two questions aren't linked)

I was able to parse a string of the form a=1&b=2&c=3 using the following code

```
NameValueCollection nameValueCollection = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(submission);
```